# How to initially have an Item when antd Dynamic Form renders for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

The default of [Dynamic Form](https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#header) had no `item` when the form renders, you need to click `+ Add field` in order to add new `item`.

I want to initially have an `item` by default when the form renders for the first time.

Default `Form` when the component renders for the first time:
[image]

I want something like this when the component renders for the first time:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to provide the initial object for the first `item` if `fields` array is empty befor you `map` over the array `fields`.

```
 fields = fields.length === 0 ? [{ name: 0, key: 0, fieldKey: 0 }] : fields;
```

[image: Edit so-60630845-form-input]

Comment: they closed this question, by the way, thanks @blueseal it solves my problem